How to return an array as a list in Flutter Dio
When I say I am a newbie I mean this is my first dart and flutter app ever. Also my first posting to stack exchange. I'm trying to consume this array using Flutter Dio and store to sqlite for an offline-first app. I get an error 400 Client error. Thanks in advance
[
    {
        "serverId": 4,
        "documentJobId": 15313,
        "serviceOn": "Jerry Brown                                                                ",
        "deliveryTo": "Jerry Brown                                                                ",
        "street1": "jcincsccncnncnc                                                      ",
        "street2": null,
        "aptSuite": null,
        "city": "nwcwncwcn                      ",
        "state": "MD                  ",
        "zip": "99999     ",
        "returnDate": "2023-12-30T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "serverId": 4,
        "documentJobId": 15313,
        "serviceOn": "David Brown                                                                ",
        "deliveryTo": "David Brown                                                                ",
        "street1": "ncjcjcncncjncn                                                           ",
        "street2": null,
        "aptSuite": null,
        "city": "Ncncnscn                    ",
        "state": "PA                  ",
        "zip": "99998     ",
        "returnDate": "2023-12-30T00:00:00"
    }

]

This is what I tried
location_model.dart
import 'dart:convert';

List<Location> FromJson(String str) =>
    List<Location>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Location.fromJson(x)));

String locationToJson(List<Location> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

//String locationToJson(List<Location> data) => json.encode(data);

class Location {

  int serverId;
  int documentJobId;
  String deliveryTo;
  String serviceOn;
  String street1;
  String? street2;
  String? aptSuite;
  String city;
  String state;
  String zip;
  DateTime returnDate;
 //  double? LonLat;

  Location({

    required this.serverId,
    required this.documentJobId,
    required this.deliveryTo,
    required this.serviceOn,
    required this.street1,
    this.street2,
    this.aptSuite,
    required this.city,
    required this.state,
    required this.zip,
    required this.returnDate,
    //    this.LonLat
  });

  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Location(
    serverId: json["serverId"],
    documentJobId: json["documentJobId"],
    deliveryTo: json["deliveryTo"],
    serviceOn: json["serviceOn"],
    street1: json["street1"],
    street2: json["street2"],
    aptSuite: json["aptSuite"],
    city: json["city"],
    state: json["state"],
    zip: json["zip"],
    returnDate: DateTime.parse(json["returnDate"]),



  //  LonLat: json["LonLat"]
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "serverId": serverId,
    "documentJobId": documentJobId,
    "deliveryTo": deliveryTo,
    "serviceOn": serviceOn,
    "street1": street1,
    "street2": street2,
    "aptSuite": aptSuite,
    "city": city,
    "state": state,
    "zip": zip,
    "returnDate": returnDate,
 //   "LonLat": LonLat
  };
}

main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ppisnet/src/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}

void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global =  MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialRoute: 'home',
        routes: {
          'home': (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
        }
    );
  }
}

location_api_provider.dart
import 'package:ppisnet/src/models/location_model.dart';
import 'package:ppisnet/src/providers/db_provider.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class LocationApiProvider {
  Future<List<Null>> getAllLocations() async {

    var url ="https://############/api/ghsjkjjkjfs";
    Response response = await Dio().get(url);

    return (response.data as List).map((location) {
      print('Inserting $location');
      DBProvider.db.createLocation(Location.fromJson(location));
    }).toList();
  }
}

db_provider.dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:ppisnet/src/models/location_model.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DBProvider {
  static Database? _database;
  static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();

  DBProvider._();

  Future<Database?> get database async {
    // If database exists, return database
    if (_database != null) return _database;

    // If database don't exists, create one
    _database  = await initDB();

    return _database;
  }

  // Create the database and the Employee table
  initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'location_manager.db');

    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
          await db.execute('CREATE TABLE Location('
              'DocumentJobId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
              'Street1 TEXT,'
              'Street2 TEXT,'
              'AptSuite TEXT,'
              'City TEXT,'
              'State TEXT,'
              'Zip TEXT'
              'ServeOn TEXT,'
              'DeliveryTo TEXT,'
              'ServerId INTEGER,'
              'LonLat DOUBLE,'
              'ReturnDate DATE'

              ')');
        });
  }

  // Insert employee on database
  createLocation(Location newLocation) async {
    await deleteAllLocations();
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db?.insert('Location', newLocation.toJson());

    return res;
  }

  // Delete all employees
  Future<int?> deleteAllLocations() async {
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db?.rawDelete('DELETE FROM Location');

    return res;
  }

  Future<List<Location>> getAllLocations() async {
    final db = await database;
    final res = await db?.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Location");

    List<Location> list =
    res!.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => Location.fromJson(c)).toList() : [];

    return list;
  }
}


home_page.dart
import 'package:ppisnet/src/providers/db_provider.dart';
import 'package:ppisnet/src/providers/location_api_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Api to sqlite'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings_input_antenna),
              onPressed: () async {
                await _loadFromApi();
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding:  EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onPressed: () async {
                await _deleteData();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
          : _buildLocationListView(),
    );
  }

  _loadFromApi() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    var apiProvider = LocationApiProvider();
    await apiProvider.getAllLocations();

    // wait for 2 seconds to simulate loading of data
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  _deleteData() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    await DBProvider.db.deleteAllLocations();

    // wait for 1 second to simulate loading of data
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });

    print('All locations deleted');
  }

  _buildLocationListView() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: DBProvider.db.getAllLocations(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else {
          return ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
              color: Colors.black12,
            ),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: Text(
                  "${index + 1}",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
                title: Text(
                    "City: ${snapshot.data[index].city} ${snapshot.data[index].state} "),               subtitle: Text('Zip: ${snapshot.data[index].zip}'),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}


E/flutter (13411): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioException [bad response]: This exception was thrown because the response has a status code of 400 and RequestOptions.validateStatus was configured to throw for this status code.
E/flutter (13411): The status code of 400 has the following meaning: "Client error - the request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled"
E/flutter (13411): Read more about status codes at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
E/flutter (13411): In order to resolve this exception you typically have either to verify and fix your request code or you have to fix the server code.
E/flutter (13411):
E/flutter (13411): #0      DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:509:7)
E/flutter (13411): 
E/flutter (13411): #1      LocationApiProvider.getAllLocations (package:ppisnet/src/providers/location_api_provider.dart:9:25)
E/flutter (13411): 
E/flutter (13411): #2      _HomePageState._loadFromApi (package:ppisnet/src/pages/home_page.dart:56:5)
E/flutter (13411): 
E/flutter (13411): #3      _HomePageState.build. (package:ppisnet/src/pages/home_page.dart:27:17)
E/flutter (13411): 
E/flutter (13411):

please add the errror stack trace

I took the array example directly from the api response. Just tested it on postman also and returns 200 ok. Any ideas?

is this normal ?     var url ="https://############/api/ghsjkjjkjfs";

no. I put bogus info in to protect api until it is secured. The api is returning the array properly checked it in browser and postman.

can you paste the curl of postman ?

Sorry I don't know how to use curl. Here is the actual url if that helps. var url="https://localhost:44370/api/mobileviewmodels". stack overflow strips out the https:

I think your code has no problems, but usually malformed URL is the most common cause of the 400 error status code.
So, check your URL again and make sure it's a correct URL.
Preferably try to test the get method on postman, or even using your browser to make sure it's returning data.
